# Add QuickLinks with powershell-pnp

Tags: pnp-powershell

Has anyone figured how to add links on a quicklinks webpart on a modern page ? I've tried examining the propertiesjson output from the webpart but looks quite unclear. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick lies in getting the webpart JSON from a workbench page.

Go to the workbench page, `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`.

On this page, configure your quick links webpart and then save it and copy the webpart data (top left ).

[image]

Store that data in a standard PS multi-line variable and then set it as PropertiesJSON of the webpart.

This is true for any modern webpart.

In the below PS script, I am adding two links, `https://google.com` and `https://yahoo.com` and then adding the webpart.

```
$jsonProps = @"
{
  "controlType": 3,
  "displayMode": 2,
  "id": "5f6ece8b-894e-4007-9f0d-9487d2d4afa9",
  "position": {
    "zoneIndex": 1,
    "sectionIndex": 1,
    "controlIndex": 1
  },
  "webPartId": "c70391ea-0b10-4ee9-b2b4-006d3fcad0cd",
  "webPartData": {
    "id": "c70391ea-0b10-4ee9-b2b4-006d3fcad0cd",
    "instanceId": "5f6ece8b-894e-4007-9f0d-9487d2d4afa9",
    "title": "Quick links",
    "description": "Add links to important documents and pages.",
    "serverProcessedContent": {
      "htmlStrings": {

      },
      "searchablePlainTexts": {
        "title": "",
        "items[0].title": "Yahoo",
        "items[1].title": "Google",
        "items[0].caption": "",
        "items[1].caption": "",
        "items[0].pictureAltText": "yahoo"
      },
      "imageSources": {
        "items[0].pictureUrl": "",
        "items[1].pictureUrl": ""
      },
      "links": {
        "baseUrl": "https:\/\/tenant.sharepoint.com\/sites\/testSite",
        "items[0].url": "https:\/\/yahoo.com",
        "items[1].url": "https:\/\/google.com",
        "items[0].renderInfo.linkUrl": "https:\/\/yahoo.com",
        "items[1].renderInfo.linkUrl": "https:\/\/google.com"
      },
      "componentDependencies": {
        "layoutComponentId": "abfccb4d-fcbc-4720-8bcc-6183ce66c391"
      }
    },
    "dataVersion": "1.0",
    "properties": {
      "items": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "itemType": 2,
          "progId": "",
          "flags": 0,
          "siteId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "webId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "listId": "",
          "uniqueId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "renderInfo": {
            "imageUrl": "https:\/\/s.yimg.com\/dh\/ap\/default\/130909\/y_200_a.png",
            "compactImageInfo": {
              "iconName": "Globe",
              "color": "",
              "imageUrl": "",
              "forceIconSize": true
            },
            "backupImageUrl": "",
            "iconUrl": "https:\/\/spoprod-a.akamaihd.net\/files\/sp-client-prod_2018-04-27.034\/icon_genericfile_4e26b79f.png",
            "accentColor": "",
            "imageFit": 2,
            "forceStandardImageSize": false,
            "isFetching": false
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 1,
          "itemType": 2,
          "progId": "",
          "flags": 0,
          "siteId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "webId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "listId": "",
          "uniqueId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "renderInfo": {
            "imageUrl": "https:\/\/spoprod-a.akamaihd.net\/files\/sp-client-prod_2018-04-27.034\/icon_link_fe14f6fb.png",
            "compactImageInfo": {
              "iconName": "Globe",
              "color": "",
              "imageUrl": "",
              "forceIconSize": true
            },
            "backupImageUrl": "",
            "iconUrl": "https:\/\/spoprod-a.akamaihd.net\/files\/sp-client-prod_2018-04-27.034\/icon_genericfile_4e26b79f.png",
            "accentColor": "",
            "imageFit": 0,
            "forceStandardImageSize": false,
            "isFetching": false
          }
        }
      ],
      "isMigrated": true,
      "layoutId": "CompactCard",
      "shouldShowThumbnail": true,
      "linkStorage": "PageLinks",
      "hideWebPartWhenEmpty": true,
      "dataProviderId": "QuickLinks",
      "webId": "6da2e540-ec43-49b7-b95b-895f9d92f428",
      "siteId": "8612321f-e57b-42c4-957f-157e1e766294"
    }
  }
}
"@
```

After that, add it on the page as :

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page "TestModernSitePage1" -DefaultWebPartType QuickLinks 
-WebPartProperties $jsonProps -Section 1 -Column 1 -Order 1
```

End result:

[image]

Here, if you check the JSON, you will find a property named, base Url, replace it with your tenant url.

Comment: hey @user3202981, did you try the above code ? If its working, could you please mark it as answer by ticking the checkmark besides the answer ?

Comment: Nice job @Gautam Sheth ! One thing I noticed is that I had to add a web part to the zone on the target page otherwise I would get an error.
I used this trick to get around the restrictions on the URL for quick links having to start with http. Client I am working with insists on using file shares and IE11 for the short term.
Cheers!
-Xopher

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution to add a Quicklins webpart with minimum data and without using complicated json :

```
Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page $page -DefaultWebPartType "QuickLinks" -WebPartProperties @{title="QuickLinks 2";items=@(@{sourceItem=@{url="https://www.google.com";itemType=2;fileExtension="";progId=""};title="Google";thumbnailType=3;id=2};@{sourceItem=@{url="https://www.youtube.com";itemType=2;fileExtension="";progId=""};title="Youtube";thumbnailType=3;id=1});hideWebPartWhenEmpty="true"}
```

Here the result :

[image]

This code can be improved to add and manage display options.